# Use of "it" and "them"

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, pronouns

Can the pronoun *it* refer to plural as in the following sentence?

> Secrets of Wealth and Provision and how to increase it.

Or should it be:

> Secrets of Wealth and Provision and how to increase them.

I would myself use *them* rather than *it*, but I just want to make sure if *it* could sometimes refer to the plural.

Answer (score 1):

*It* can have a plural antecedent when the antecedent, although ostensibly plural, is perceived as a unified entity. An example might be ‘I don’t like thunder and lightning. It frightens me.'

Kris is right in his comment below, and I have consequently deleted the second part of my answer.

Comment: Sorry Barry, you may have missed a point there. The subject of the sentence is *Wealth and Provision* because *increase* applies to that phrase not to *Secrets*.

Comment: @Kris. Yes, of course, quite right. Answer amended.

Answer (score -1):

*... increase **it*** is correct.

Note the capitalization provided for clarity: *Wealth and Provision* is a term here referring to a **single abstract entity**.

This alludes to

> "*The greatest **wealth and provision** from heaven **is** the love of our Father manifest in Christ Jesus.*"  [emphasis mine]
>   <sub>see: [2. Preparing for Troubled Times – Part II](http://www.openheaven.com/forums/forum_posts.asp?TID=41869&PN=1)</sub>

Comment: It's arguable whether the making available and the appropriation should be considered as a single entity (see eg Heb 2:3); I'd prefer _The provision God makes, the greatest wealth we can have, ..._. God's provision and what we _may_ appropriate **is** a single entity. I'm not sure how we can increase God's provision (if the OP actually is quoting this source).